# Magento 2: delete all cart price rules (promotions) programmatically

Tags: magento2, sales, price-rules

I want to delete all the price rules programmatically. How can I achieve this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the delete sales rule controller: `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Controller/Adminhtml/Promo/Quote/Delete.php`. As we can see, we can use `\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory` to delete the invidual sales rule.

We also can use `\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleRepository::deleteById($ruleId)`.

For the multi rows, we can use `Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory`;

```
   /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory */
    $om = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    foreach ($om->getItems() as $item) {
        /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $item */
       $item->delete();
    }
```

At Database level: Just delete rows `salesrule`

```
DELETE FROM salesrule;
```

The other tables will be trigger to update.

Answer (score 2):

Create a test.php in root folder and use below code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$collectionFactory = $obj->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection');
$collectionFactory->walk('delete');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
public function getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria);
```

To get the rule and you can use `public function deleteById($ruleId);` to delete any rule in interface `Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface`.

Magento recommends to use `interfaces` as good Magento2 coding practice.